# progress не обновляется на новое значение

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться,

```
myProfile.currentCaloriesDay = sumCaloriesDay();
```

на 135 строке, почти в самом конце. Функция `sumCaloriesDay()` перезаписывает значение объекта `myProfile.currentCaloriesDay`, но при этом сама шкала прогресса не обновляется. Если же вручную ее указать, обновляется. В консоле проверяю, значение функция возвращает. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
const myProfile = {
  mainGoalCalories: 78000,
  currentCalories: 6000,
  normCaloriesDay: 1500,
  currentCaloriesDay: 0,
};

const body = document.querySelector('body');
const title = document.createElement('h1');
const mainForm = document.createElement('form');
const progressMainGoalWrapper = document.createElement('div');
const progressDaysGoalWrapper = document.createElement('div');

body.appendChild(title);

progressMainGoalWrapper.classList.add('progressMainGoalWrapper');
title.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', progressMainGoalWrapper);

title.textContent = 'Сервис по учету каллорий!';
title.classList.add('title');


const progressMainGoalTitle = document.createElement('h2');
progressMainGoalTitle.textContent = `Основная цель, потерять ${myProfile.mainGoalCalories} каллорий`;
progressMainGoalTitle.classList.add('progressMainGoalTitle');
progressMainGoalWrapper.appendChild(progressMainGoalTitle);


const progressMainGoal = document.createElement('progress');
progressMainGoalWrapper.appendChild(progressMainGoal);
progressMainGoal.classList.add('progress');
progressMainGoal.setAttribute('max', myProfile.mainGoalCalories);
progressMainGoal.setAttribute('value', myProfile.currentCalories);


const progressDaysGoalTitle = document.createElement('h2');
progressDaysGoalTitle.textContent = `Съедено за день ${myProfile.currentCaloriesDay} ккал, из ${myProfile.normCaloriesDay} ккал.`;
progressDaysGoalTitle.classList.add('progressDaysGoalTitle');
progressDaysGoalWrapper.appendChild(progressDaysGoalTitle);
progressDaysGoalWrapper.classList.add('progressDaysGoalWrapper');
body.appendChild(progressDaysGoalWrapper);


const progressDayGoal = document.createElement('progress');
progressDaysGoalWrapper.appendChild(progressDayGoal);
progressDayGoal.classList.add('progressDay')
progressDayGoal.setAttribute('max', myProfile.normCaloriesDay);
progressDayGoal.setAttribute('value', myProfile.currentCaloriesDay);


body.appendChild(mainForm);
mainForm.classList.add('mainForm');

function creationInput(name, placeholderName, width) {
  mainForm.appendChild(name);
  name.classList.add('input');
  name.setAttribute('placeholder', `${placeholderName}`);
  name.style.width = `${width}`;
}

const inputProductName = document.createElement('input');
creationInput(inputProductName, 'Название продукта');
inputProductName.id = 'product'; 


const inputProductCalories = document.createElement('input');
creationInput(inputProductCalories, 'Калорийность на 100 грамм.');
inputProductCalories.id = 'caloriesProduct'; 

const inputGramEaten = document.createElement('input');
creationInput(inputGramEaten, 'Съедено грамм');
inputGramEaten.id = 'gram'; 

const buttonSubmitForm = document.createElement('button');
buttonSubmitForm.textContent = 'Записать данные';
buttonSubmitForm.classList.add('buttonSubmit');
mainForm.appendChild(buttonSubmitForm);

const titleTable = document.createElement('h2');
titleTable.textContent = 'Таблица по съеденным продуктам';
body.appendChild(titleTable);

const tableHTML = `
<table class="table" cols="4" width="800">
   <tr>
      <th>Продукт</th>
      <th>Кол-во грамм</th>
      <th>Кал. на 100 грамм</th>
      <th>Всего кал.</th>
   </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Сыр</td>
      <td>118</td>
      <td>344</td>
      <td class="sumCaloriesProduct">545</td>
      </tr>

            <tr>
      <td>Сыр</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td class="sumCaloriesProduct">524</td>
      </tr>
</table>
`;

titleTable.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', tableHTML);


function addNewProducte(product, gram, caloriesProduct) {
  return `
      <tr>
      <td>${product}</td>
      <td>${gram}</td>
      <td>${caloriesProduct}</td>
      <td class="sumCaloriesProduct">${(gram / 100) * caloriesProduct}</td>
      </tr>
   `;
}

const table = document.querySelector('table');
const tdArr = table.querySelectorAll('.sumCaloriesProduct');

function sumCaloriesDay () {
   let allSumCaloriesDay = 0;
   tdArr.forEach((item) => {
     allSumCaloriesDay += +item.innerText;
   });
   return allSumCaloriesDay;
}

buttonSubmitForm.addEventListener('click', (btn) => {
  btn.preventDefault();
  myProfile.currentCaloriesDay = sumCaloriesDay();
  const product = document.getElementById('product').value;
  const gram = document.getElementById('gram').value;
  const caloriesProduct = document.getElementById('caloriesProduct').value;
  table.innerHTML += addNewProducte(product, gram, caloriesProduct);
  // myProfile.currentCaloriesDay = sumCaloriesDay();
  document.querySelector('form').reset();
});
```

```css
body {
   font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
   background-color: rgb(35, 35, 58);
   color: rgb(255, 94, 0);
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.progressMainGoalWrapper{
   border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 98);
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: rgba(253, 238, 238, 0.151);
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   width: 500px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.progressDaysGoalWrapper{
      border: 2px solid rgb(238, 255, 0);
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: rgba(253, 238, 238, 0.151);
   margin-bottom: 25px;
   width: 500px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.calc-form{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

.title {
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   color: white;
}

.progressMainGoalTitle {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: rgb(0, 255, 98)
}

.progressDaysGoalTitle{
      padding: 0;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: rgb(238, 255, 0);
}

.input{
   margin: 0 10px 0 0 ;
   background-color: inherit;
   border: 1px solid rgb(255, 94, 0);
   color: rgb(255, 94, 0);
   font-size: 16px;
   height: 30px;
   width: 200px;
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}
.input::placeholder {
      color: rgb(255, 94, 0);
}

.progress {
   background-color: rgb(0, 255, 98);
   border-radius: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   width: 200px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 
.progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
   background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
      border-radius: 20px;
}
 
.progress::-webkit-progress-value {
   background-color: rgb(0, 255, 98);
      border-radius: 20px;
}
 
.progress::-moz-progress-bar {
   background-color: rgb(0, 255, 98);
      border-radius: 20px;
}

.buttonSubmit{
   background-color: rgb(255, 94, 0);
   color: white;
   border: none;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bold;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: .5s ease-in;
   display: block;
   margin: 20px auto;
   width: 100%;
}

.buttonSubmit:hover {
   background-color: rgb(5, 173, 47)
}

.progressDay {
   background-color: rgb(238, 255, 0);;
   border-radius: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   width: 200px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 
.progressDay::-webkit-progress-bar {
   background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
      border-radius: 20px;
}
 
.progressDay::-webkit-progress-value {
   background-color:  rgb(238, 255, 0);;
      border-radius: 20px;
}
 
.progressDay::-moz-progress-bar {
   background-color:   rgb(238, 255, 0);;
      border-radius: 20px;
}

.table{
   background-color: rgb(255, 94, 0);
   color: white;
   border: 2px solid white;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th{
   border: solid 1px rgb(255, 255, 255);
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Укажите строку 135, а то считать долго.

Comment: myProfile.currentCaloriesDay = sumCaloriesDay();

Comment: Значение `myProfile.currentCaloriesDay` не влияет на `value .progressDay` по этому шкала не обновляется..

Comment: Добавь  `document.querySelector('.progressDay').value += sumCaloriesDay();`

Comment: Большое спасибо!